# Nestjs containerization | Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nestjs

I'm writing docker compose file for nest application. I have asked gpt for help and it gave me some guidlines and now i dont know where to continue search so here i am :)

For this moment i need dev environment so services nestjs, mysql and reddis is enough
What i'm looking for is best practises for building performant and secured application.

Saw docker secrets, someone write it prevents leaking for example db password. But how? If someone gains access on server, it could read from file, its plain text right? Only encrypted is injected inside container.

Second: using env_file instead of writing environment variables inside docker-compose file, or main .env file.

Skipping health check, its not relevant at the moment.

Any information will be helpful, thanks in advance 3>

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  nestjs:
    build:
      context: ./docker/nestjs
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: nestjs
    tty: true
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - redis
    user: node
    working_dir: /srv/nestjs
    volumes:
      - ./:/srv/nestjs
  mysql:
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: always
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    volumes:
      - redis:/data

secrets:
  mysql_root_password:
    file: mysql_root_password
  mysql_password:
    file: mysql_password

volumes:
  mysql:
  redis:
```

Comment: Are you trying to write a production-ready *docker-compose* file or just for local development?

Comment: For this moment i need environment for local development, but its placed on vps and dont want to leak credentials, dont care about database, other rest services credentials and source code are the most important for me to keep safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For local development, you don't need to worry about secrets and credentials. You don't even need to build the app as a Docker image. The following config is sufficient.

```yaml
services:
  app:
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - redis
    image: node:lts-alpine
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    environment:
      DB_HOST: mysql
      DB_PORT: 3306
      DB_USER: root
      DB_PASS: root
      REDIS_HOST: redis
      # ...other env vars with "test" / "dummy" vals
    command:
      - npm
      - run
      - start:dev
  mysql:
    image: mariadb:lts
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    volumes:
      - redis:/data
volumes:
  mysql:
  redis:
```

Then you start the app by running:

```bash
docker compose up app
```

Comment: Since this setup isn't using Docker's image system for anything, you could even consider deleting the `app` container entirely, and running `npm run start:dev` on the host system.  This gets around several problems with Docker filesystem synchronization not working and around what exactly is in the `node_modules` directory.  If you add `ports:` to the `mysql` and `redis` containers you could use these unmodified containers to back your application.

Comment: (...though I think the original question was asking a little more towards security-oriented best practices, and I typically recommend deleting the application `volumes:` block entirely.)

Comment: The purpose of my setup is to fully utilize Docker for local development. If you remove `app` container and expose ports of `mariadb` and `redis` to the host, you're basically back to thee typical development setup where you install all the tools in your machine and use those. The reason for using Docker for development purpose is to share single environment across every major platform so that all developers share the exact copy of the setup and can replicate that without breaking a sweat.